# Ruby 2.2.4 lexing an assignment in a conditional

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, lexical-analysis, operator-precedence

What is the difference between these two lines of code?

```
a = (b if (b = "test"))
a =  b if (b = "test")
```

The first runs fine and sets both `a` and `b` to `test`, but the second throws an error:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object

I would have assumed that for the second line, Ruby would evaluate `b = "test"` first, then `if "test"`,  and finally `a = b`. What is actually going on?

(Ruby version 2.2.4)

Comment: Neither of these work in ruby 2.3 (just as it should be).

Comment: Devon, you can inspect [instruction sequences](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/RubyVM/InstructionSequence.html) for both lines and find the difference yourself. I personally wouldn't bother, because this code should never be used and it doesn't reproduce in latest ruby anyway.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both lines won't work. And both lines will work. It is schrödinger expression :).

You can run it twice in a new repl:

```
a =  b if b = "test"
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object
a =  b if b = "test"
#=> "test"
```

Let's look deeper, open a new repl:

```
defined(b)
#=> nil
a = b if b = "test"
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object
defined(b)
#=> local-variable
b
#=> "test"
a = b if b = "test"
#=> "test"
```

So actually Ruby has evaluated `b = "test"` part and defined this variable in current scope. Both expressions `a = b` and `if b = "test"` were executed. More than it, if statement is executed before assignment statement:

```
c = p("assignment") && b if b = p("if") && "test"
#=> "if"
#=> "assignment"
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `b' for main:Object
```

But `b` variable was not defined in scope of assignment statement when it was evaluated first time. And on the second approach it was already defined so you received correct result.

So, **Never do assignments in this way**

Comment: Ah, repl might be the answer, yes. :)

Comment: So it looks like while I was testing this issue I ran into the unfortunate case of having it always work the one way and never the other, as a coincidence of ordering. Thanks!